Change CPU frequency in Linux
I have another PC and I want to install Linux on it but I don't know if Linux can change the CPU frequency so I'm asking for guidance.Can you change the CPU frequency in Linux Ubuntu?
The CPU is AMD A8 6500(a quad core)

Yes, Linux can do that. However, please edit your questions and specify whether you expect Linux to change the CPU frequency automatically depending on the work load of the system or if you want to manually change / overwrite the CPU frequency.
